# How to set web app as default (no subdirectory in url) using Zend Server Cartdridge in Openshift?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2, openshift, zend-server

I am creating a web app in Zend Framework 2. Deployed it to a Zend Server 6 gear in OpenShift using Zend Studio 12, to my surprise when I tried the url: http://myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com I got a page with info on the Zend Server itself, then I logged in to the server at http://myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/ZendServer/Login to realize that the app was created to run in this url: http://myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/MyAppName.

This is definitely not what I wanted, since the users won't like (I bet) having to write the address plus the app name as a subfolder (/MyAppName). I know that when adding the DNS config the name will be shorter, but still will look like "http://myApp.com/MyApp", it doesn't make sense to me, it is like having to type the Google Url like "http://google.com/app"  that is not nice (for saying the least).

Is there any way I can configure Zend Server, OpenShift Gear, maybe .htaccess or something like that in order to avoid having to use the subfolder part of the url and having this app as the default for my Zend Server Cartdrige?

This may sound simple but I have been researching this for hours. Probably I am too much into the problem so that I can't find the solution (even with lots of coffee), I'll appreciate any help/comments.

Thanks.